# Android: アイコンのみのTabHost

Tags: android, java, xml

下図のように`TabHost`を制作したいと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.linearLayout2);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("試験");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

というコードから`setIndicator`を削除すると、アプリが停止されます。

画像の通りに、どうやってアイコンのみのタブホストが作れるでしょうか。

この質問には状態によってアイコン変更という課題を触れないでおきましょう。

Comment: tabSpec.setIndicator("");のように空文を設定してみるのはやってみましたか。

Comment: 出来たようです。お礼を差し上げるかもしれませんから、回答を作っていただいても宜しいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ご要望により、コメントから、回答に転記させていただきます。

tabSpec.setIndicator("");のように空文を設定してみるのはやってみましたか。

以上です。

Comment: はい、問題が無さそうです。Androidに素人ですからこのように簡単に解決できるって思いませんでした。